# Error in project after changing field in the model Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

First, I added an extra field to my project, then I typed `Enable-Migrations` in the console, which executed successfully, then I typed `add-migration` myprojectname`. The last step was`Update-Database`and after this step I got`The project 'class_project' failed to build.` in the console.

The error is :

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error CS0426  The type name 'Models' does not exist in the type 'class_project'   class_project   C:\Users\internship\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\class_project\class_project\Migrations\Configuration.cs   16  Active

I really have no idea why am I getting this, since i followed some clear instructions.

Can someone help, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is in the error you will get when you try to build the project.

Comment: Long shot guess: It may be as simple as your class is called 'Model' and you pressed Ctrl+s to save and now you have 'Models'

Comment: My class is called Post, actually. And the error is in my question. No idea why i get it.. That's why I am asking here

Comment: What is the code at the line with the error (in Configuration.cs line 16)?

Comment: protected override void Seed(class_project.Models.Post.PostContext context)

Comment: What is the 'namespace' line in the file with the Post class?

Comment: namespace class_project.Models

Comment: What is the error if you change the line to Seed( Models..... - i.e. remove 'class_project.'

Comment: Actually now it's able to build the project. But I can't use the database. gives me invalid operation exception when trying to access some of the controller methods

Comment: ok, wait. it worked after i did an update-database in the console. Thanks so much, mate!! :)))